# Finding a date (dimmed as string) in entire workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search all worksheets for a date, and when found replace the date by "yes".

I have the code below:

```
Sub Aftekenen()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range
Dim Datum As String

Datum = "28-12-2015"

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With Sh.UsedRange

    Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=Datum)

    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        Do Until Loc Is Nothing
            Loc.Value = "Yes"
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
        Loop
    End If
End With
Set Loc = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

However the code runs, however it never reaches the For each loop. When I remove the "-" so the date will become a number it finds it. However when the dashes are present the code does not find any fitting value, however these are present.

Comment: Can't replicate.  Is the date that you're searching for a string in the Worksheet, or is it a date?

Comment: You should explicitly set the other parameters to your Find statement.  As written the Find will use whatever settings were used the last it was used, whether by code or the user.

Answer (score 0):

try this, `for each ... next` method with comparing `.Text` (not value, because of value of the cell for `"28-12-2015"` is `42366`), it works well but some users have an objection to this method by some reasons, as for me **less coding better reading**

```
Sub Aftekenen()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, Loc As Range, Datum As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Datum = "28-12-2015"
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Loc In Sh.UsedRange
            If Loc.Text = Datum Then Loc.Value = "Yes"
        Next Loc
    Next Sh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

## update

if you prefer `.find` method then for searching of the dates is required to switch `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat` to format of the cells with dates, due to the date in `.text` is `18-05-2015`, but `.value` is `42142`

below is your updated variant

```
Sub Aftekenen()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range
Dim Datum As String

Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"

Datum = "28-12-2015"

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With Sh.UsedRange

    Set Loc = .Cells.Find(Datum, , xlValues, , , , True, , True)

    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        Do Until Loc Is Nothing
            Loc.Value = "Yes"
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
        Loop
    End If
End With
Set Loc = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody voted down without any comments, code works fine : )

Comment: Do you realize that your code compares each and every used cell in the whole workbook? The original code didn't, and for good reason. Not only that this is bad advice but you haven't touched the main problem: the difference between a date and a string value.

Comment: @user1016274 of course I realize that the code will compare each cell in usedrange for each worksheet, and this is will not be much slower due to this is not `.select` method in first. the second is that I catched the main problem, as you already mentioned <<difference between a date and string value>>, and that's why comparing goes with cell text instead cell value. also `Application.ScreenUpdating` can be changed to speed up code. And that's why I did't see reason why answer was voted down, due to the solution works well for such purposes.

Comment: Vasily, valid points, and your added code is what I would prefer for performance reasons. FYI, I didn't downvote.

Comment: I did not know `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat` before, nice.