# How do I format the date in .find()?

Tags: vba, date, date-formatting

My VBA code below determines whether a given date is a working day or not. When it is not a working day, it will output the previous day's date.

The problem is that it seems not to be respecting the date format. For example, when searching for 01/02/2015 it seemingly takes the date as 02/01/2015. Which causes a problem as 01/02/2015 may not be a working day, while 02/01/2015 could be.

Here's the code:

```
Function FechaHabil(Fecha As Date, Rango As Range)

  'Rango is the set of non working dates
  'Fecha is the desired date to find

   Dim Flag As Integer
   Dim FechaFinal As Date

   FechaFinal = Format(Fecha, "dd/mm/yyyy")
   Flag = 0
   Do While Flag <> 1
     Set Busca = Rango.Find(FechaFinal, LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not Busca Is Nothing Then
       FechaFinal = DateAdd("d", -1, FechaFinal)
       Flag = 0
     Else
       Flag = 1
     End If
   Loop
   FechaHabil = FechaFinal
```

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-dates.htm

Comment: similar issue has been discussed here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30293508/4230409

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear - it was hard to read at first, but I've corrected some spelling mistakes and introduced key aspects to the question sooner. Also I changed the white-spacing for the code - not sure if it's correct, I don't use VBA, so feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```